# Hybrid SSR and Static with Vue.js or Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-ssr

I am building a website that some pages are better to be static, such as `/about`, `/access`, etc.
But some pages such as for as `/products` need to be dynamic as it is fetching data from API.

So I'm wondering, is there any way to implement this using Vue.js or nuxt.js?
Any hints or references will be very appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can. You just won't add any API requests handling on those static pages.

Comment: So does that means all pages that doesn't have API calls will be automatically be rendered as static on the build process?